# Parsing HTTP Request using HTTPCORE

Tags: java, http

I am working on HTTP Logging module of Web Security project. I need to parse HTTP request of Dataset. How can I do this using HTTPCORE API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.